# Проблема с передачей и работой с переменными внутри функции

Tags: c, функции, указатели

После перехода на функцию z1 программа перестает работать

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int Vvod( int *array, int n1, int n2);
int Z1(int* array, int* m1, int* m2, int d);
int *mass, n1, n2, i, j, d;
int *m1, *m2;
int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        printf_s("Stroki i stolbcy\n");
        scanf_s("%d%d", &n1, &n2);
        printf_s("Vvedite luboye chislo d\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &d);
        m1 = &n1;
        m2 = &n2;
        Vvod(mass,n1,n2);
        Z1(mass,m1,m2,d);
    }
    return 0;
    _getch();
}
int Vvod(int *array, int n1, int n2)
{
    array = (int*)malloc(n1*n2 * sizeof(int));
    printf_s("Please, type all the elements of the array\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        {
            printf_s("Element [%d][%d] ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf_s("%d", (array +i*n2 +j));

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int Z1(int* array, int* m1, int* m2, int d)
{
    int l = 0;
    if (*m1 == *m2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = (*m1 - i - 1); j < *m1; j++)
            {
                if ( *(array +i*(*m2)+j) == d)
                {
                    l = 1;
                    printf_s("There is 'd' in secondary dioganal \n");
                }
                else if (l != 1.0)
                {
                    printf_s("There is no such an element in secondary dioganal \n");
                }
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("The matrix isn't square");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOveflow. Что означает "программа перестает работать", известно только Вам.

Comment: visual предлагает либо отладку либо завершение программы, простите,  я новичок

Comment: Хорошо, я уже мысленно заглянул в Ваш экран :).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает! :)

Comment: На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значение переменной `mass` в результате вызова функции `Vvod` не меняется, и в `Z1` передается неинициализированный указатель.

```
int* Vvod(int n1, int n2)
{
    int* array = (int*)malloc(n1*n2 * sizeof(int));
    ...
    return array;
}

mass = Vvod(n1,n2);
```